# gnome-desktop docker image works with Linux Mint Host but not CentOS?

Tags: gnome, docker, centos6, dbus, selinux

I'm using this docker imagine from the docker repo: traxtopel/docker-centos-gnome-desktop

https://index.docker.io/u/traxtopel/docker-centos-gnome-desktop/

I have a Linux Mint system with Docker 0.9.0 installed that can run the image and launch vncserver with a gnome-session without any problems.

However, when I run the same image on my CentOS6 system (also docker version 0.9.0) and attempt to launch a gnome-session I get the following:

> Failed to start message bus:  Failed to open "/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/dbus_contexts": No  such file or directory
> EOF in dbus-launch reading address from bus daemon

I also tried to launch a gnome-terminal which works in the Linux Mint host but produces the following on my CentOS6 host.

> Failed to get the session bus: /bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: EOF in dbus-launch reading address from bus daemon
>
> Falling back to non-factory mode.
> Failed to summon the GConf demon; exiting.  Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: /bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: EOF in dbus-launch reading address from bus daemon
> )

Since both docker versions are the same, and they are using the same docker image, my only guess is it has to do with the hosts kernel version or possibly the hosts selinux configuration.

Linux Mint Kernel: 3.8.0-19-generic
CentOS6 Kernel: 2.6.32-431.5.1

Any ideas what is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue has something to do with selinux.  I don't have all the details or a "proper" fix but the Linux Mint system was not running selinux while the CentOS6 system was.

I had initially ruled this out since when selinux is put into permissive mode the same behavior occurs.  Disabling selinux entirely and rebooting the host system fixes the issue though.

Trying to determine the root cause, I ran selinux in permissive mode and tailed the /var/log/audit/audit.log file however nothing is written out to the log concerning this issue when gnome-terminal or gnome-session is run from the docker image.

If anyone has any better solutions please post however it seems a solution is to disable selinux on the host system.